# Why can not save in opengeosuite ? message: No space left on device

Tags: boundless-suite

I have installed opengeosuite in Ubuntu server, and configure to use gwc by leaflet. It was ok and can upload layer using PostGIS, however now it shows this message when try to modify sld style:

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Cannot save anything. Any ideas?

[image]

when run in ubuntu: df -h space disk is ok an availble.

Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          7,9G  4,0K  7,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         1,6G  868K  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/mail10--vg-root   259G   76G  171G  31% /
none                          4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                          5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                          7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /run/shm
none                          100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     236M   39M  185M  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_mail-LogVol00  825G  776M  782G   1% /opt

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this isuue:

The real problem was the memory zise in Tomcat 7 configuration.
when chek the memory

System load:  3.79                Processes:          242
  Usage of /:   29.0% of 258.43GB   Users logged in:    0
  Memory usage: 96%                  IP address for em1: 192.168.1.108
  Swap usage:   8%

Then we modify the increase and change defautl configuration.
-Xms set initial Java heap size
-Xmx set maximum Java heap size
-Xss set java thread stack size

that all and now the memory is:

System load:  3.79                Processes:          242
  Usage of /:   29.0% of 258.43GB   Users logged in:    0
  Memory usage: 6%                  IP address for em1: 192.168.1.108
  Swap usage:   0%

Memry usage now is 6%, and can save and Geoserver is ok.

Armando.